# How can I create this warped circular text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

Someone asked me to recreate a logo in Illustrator.
The original logo was made with an old commodore 64 computer.
I can't get the logo rounded / stretched.

Original logo:

[image: Original logo]

Logo that I created yet:

[image: logo I created yet]

How can I achieve the warp shaped text?

Comment: You got this far by using a  circular text path,  correct? Might be worth adding that to the question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Type your fonts (in this case I guess and you suggest Times New Roman) and outline it.

[image]

2. Drag it into `Brushes`. Choose `Art Brush` and use the default settings.

[image]

3. Create a circle, and while choosing it, click on the newly created brush. Choose appropriate `stroke` to scale the fonts' height. Rotate it a little bit to match your original logo.

[image]

4. Now it is time to `expand` your circle into a shape.

[image]

5. Make three copies of the shape, and assign them the colors of the front, the start of the shadow, and the end of the shadow of the original logo.

[image]

6. Choose the two copies for the shadows, `make` them into a `blend`.

[image]

7. In the `blend` options, set as many blending copies as you like.

[image]
[image]

8. Finally, move the front copy onto the shadow, and you are done...

[image]